# using fragment code for one page serving many purposes

Tags: php, html, fragment

I want to refer users to a custom page upon 401/404 errors etc using something like the fragment code.

I want to use *one page* ie error.html

that calls elements specific to that error, ie

error.html#401

without having to create error401.html, error404.html etc - however I can't seem to use the fragment code to this effect.

i have been trying:

```
<a name="401">
<title>401 - Authorisation Required</title>
<h1>Authorisation Required</h1>
<p>
<h2>Blah blah sorry</h2>
</a>

<a name="404">
...etc
</a>
```

Does anyone have any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want? To show only the content of the anchor that matches the hash name? The markup is invalid btw

Comment: So if anything fails you'll redirect users to 404 again and again? use .htaccess instead

Comment: hi @OneTrickPony - yes exactly - to show only the content that matches the hashtag. mr alien, i'm using .htaccess, but want one page instead of numerous...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes exactly - to show only the content that matches the hashtag

This is not possible using PHP, because the fragment part of the URL (`#401`) is never sent to the server. And even if it worked, you would need an if block in your markup.

**Using CSS (see [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/css/%3atarget)):**

```
a{display: none;}    
a:target{display: block;}
```

I would reconsider doing this though. There's nothing wrong in having multiple files handling different error messages.

---

For valid markup:

```
<a name="401"></a>
<div>
  <title>401 - Authorisation Required</title>
  <h1>Authorisation Required</h1>
  <h2>Blah blah sorry</h2>
</div>

<a name="404"></a>
<div>
   ...etc
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a + div{display: none;}    
a:target + div{display: block;}
```